# How to get a trusted code signing certificate(.pfx) for non-store UWP application?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, pfx, code-signing-certificate

Our UWP application will be released outside of the Microsoft Store since it is a Line-Of-Business application. I scoured the internet for references and what I have gathered is that for users to be able to install our UWP application, it needs to be signed with a Trusted Certificate.
A trusted certificate can be obtained from any Certificate Authority(CA) by submitting a Certificate-Signing-Request(CSR) for code signing cert.

Now I haven't tried to get a certificate yet, as it involves payments. So, I want to be sure **if I can get a .pfx certificate from the Certificate Authorities for signing our UWP application?**

Will CA have the provision to select a Code signing certificate for UWP? and NOT an SSL certificate?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should sign your app with a *code-signing* certificate that is trusted on each device to which you deploy the app.

You would typically use a certificate that is provided by your organization if you belong to one. The other recommended option is to purchase a certificate from a third-party provider whose public root certificate is already trusted by Windows.

If you do a Bing or Google search for "code signing certificate", you should find some trusted providers.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have looked into providers like DigiCert, which have a clear instruction on getting the certificate. But the customer is looking at a different provider and I haven't been able to get any documentation on them. Therefore, asking if certificate providers can provide .PFX ? There are ways to export it via MMC, but just want to be sure. Before any money is spent.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is? The certificate may be exported and installed as a .pfx.

Comment: I mean he asks WHERE to get the nessesary .pfx certificate is something you make by urself or can be asked from somehwere?